# How to get current date time format in SQlite?

Tags: sqlite

I am using sqlite for local database in mobile and in my database. i want to know that

How to get current date format in SQLITE? I want to get date in the next format: `MM/dd/yyyy`

Comment: I want current format like MM/dd/yyyy like this.
any idea how to get it ?

Comment: See the linked documentation for formatting too.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

To get the current date you can use:

```
SELECT date('now');
```

Note: This is NOT a server date, it's the same time you get if you query the date and time directly from your application because SQLITE runs in-process.

It's mostly useful for putting a current time into a table or for some simple calculations if your language's date processing is very poor.

To do the calculations see the [SQLITE Documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

See the docs for formatting too for example:

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', datetime('now'))
```

Comment: in order to get the time you have to use datetime('now') otherwise it will only return date.

Comment: for `MM/dd/yyyy` use `select strftime('%m/%d/%Y', 'now', 'localtime')`

Answer (score 4):

According to the [SQLite documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) as of this writing (3/30/2020), in the section titled "The DEFAULT clause", it is recommended that a constant value be used instead of a sub-query.

In my experimentation, I also ran into issues with the SQLite CREATE TABLE statement that was generated during model creation by EF Core 3.0 when using SELECT datetime('now'). The SQLite data provider complained of a syntax error when using a SELECT statement within the CREATE table statement. As such, I would recommend using the **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP** keyword.

Answer (score 0):

for your concrete case, this is what you need:

```
strftime('%m/%d/%Y',date('now'))
```